# Basic Java GUI design

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In the GUI book we use in class there are many examples of how graphical user interfaces are made in Java. So many examples, that I'm very confused regarding which one should be used when it comes down to a big application.

So I've seen examples

- in which the main class extends `JFrame`
- where the `JFrame` object is created inside the `main` method
- where the main class extends `JFrame` AND implements `ActionEvent` interface
- where Listener classes are declared inside the main class

Sure, I can work with all of these, but right now, as I don't have any kind of experience, I don't see the benefit of using any of them. Is actually one of them the correct way to do it or it depends on my sittuation?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd argue that which of these alternatives you pick is ultimately unimportant In a "real" app, you're going to want to structure it according to MVC principles, and doing this higher-level design right is much more important than the technicalities of how exactly the binding (which should be as thin and "dumb" as possible) between the view and the controller is implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Is A" or "Has A"?  This is the question that should be asked when considering extending a class.  If the new class "Is A" frame, extend frame, but if the class just needs a reference to a frame, **don't extend**.

In fact, if a custom component ***is*** required, extend a `JComponent` or `JPanel`, then add that to a frame, ..applet, window, `JInternalFrame`, dialog, constraint of a layout, part of a split pane..

### Listeners

As to the listeners.  Rather than traverse a huge `if`/`else` structure in the single `actionPerformed()` method to determine the required action, it is more optimal to either:

1. Create a listener for each control that needs it.
2. Create an instance of an [`AbstractAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) that might be used for multiple controls ('copy' button, menu item etc.).

### Summary

So (generally) for the:

1. `JFrame`, don't extend.
2. Listeners, create and add as needed.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you'd not extend `JFrame`, but then go ahead and extend `JPanel` for no good reason. (But do extend `JApplet`, just don't do much in the subclass.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline *"extend JPanel for no good reason."*  What did I write that suggested that?  I was not explicit about when a custom component should be preferred over other means of creating a GUI.  But my point is that you might want a custom component, more often than a custom frame.  I cannot think of a single case for the latter.

Comment: @trashgod  You mean as in [`PanelUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/PanelUI.html)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes; although it's typically minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it depends on the situation. One basic rule when coding is to "code to abstract classes or interfaces".

So, in a nutshell, have a class extending (or implementing) a JFrame (or whatever interface or class) and/or have one doing the same thing with ActionListener.

It is all about the maintainability, flexibility and cleanness of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Standard approach: use EventQueue in method main, that creates main form. In that case all your operations will be asynchronous

Comment: When using Swing, this happens behind the scenes anyway. I'm not sure what's the point of doing this by hand, and in any case this doesn't seem to answer the OP's question

Comment: You mean `public static void main(String[] args) { java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { methodToStartSwingGUI(); }}); }`? Yes, do that.

Answer (score 0):

> in which the main class extends JFrame

- the main calss doesn't have to extend JFrame. if it doesn't you should create a JFrame object like you do with any other class

> where the JFrame object is created inside the main method

- If the MainClass extend JFrame it created inside the c'tor (in the super() ).